# User status detection in chat application

Tags: windows, chat

I am developing one chat application,How its possible to detect user interaction with PC to display status like away or online as we can see in application like skype? If this is specific to only browser tab then we can easily done it with 
jquery mouse listener but how its possible at windows level?

Comment: If I'm correct, you want to develop a chat application for a PC and you want to know when your application gains and loses focus so you can update your chat state. May I know the framework you are using? Either a third party library or native widgets and network sockets and also the language will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks buddy, I am using websocket in java for this application